# Efforts and motivation on sanctification

Tags: sanctification

Does sanctification require effort on part of the believer, God, or both combined? If on part of the believer, then who provides motivation for sanctification, God or self?

Comment: It depends on who you ask. Are you looking for an answer from a particular tradition?

Comment: I am looking for answers either from tradition or one's own thoughts.

Comment: Note that answers from "one's own thoughts are absolutely not within the site guidelines.  http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer  But +1 because this is a good question otherwise.

Comment: @DavidStratton To be more specific, I'm looking for some sort of deductive reasoning, where the assumptions are either doctrinal or biblical, but may make use of one's own conclusions. I believe that this falls within community guidelines, under the first bullet of the list that you linked to me.

Comment: The question was good.  I voted it up.  The comment you made was what I was addressing.  I'm sorry if I sound like a nag.  I mean it in a helpful way, to help a newcomer figure the site out.  It took me a while to realize the difference between this site and normal discussion forums, and I am simply trying to help newcomers understand.  Please don't take any of my comments as hostile or judgmental in any way.

Comment: Okay, is the clarification of my comment acceptable?

Comment: @DavidStratton I appreciate your help in figuring this site out.

Comment: Yep.  I think you're in the clear here.

Comment: @AlexHeuman just to fill you in a bit here. We strongly prefer if people who ask questions specify some kind of doctrinal preference. That way the answers can be tailored to the person asking the question. Otherwise your leaving yourself open from answers from anywhere. Because ultimately as Bruce said, the answer to this depends on who you ask. We don't really do all that well with questions about truth. If you'd like to ask for Biblical backing for a subject we can do that OK. but if you want to know the facts, that's rolling the dice and depending on the day and mod viewing may get closed.

Comment: I believe that their is an absolute truth answer to this questions, however I believe that we may not know it. Therefore, I am asking that people give biblical support to provide credence to what they say, so that perhaps a logical conclusion could be drawn. If I want to hear the answer from several different denominations, do I have to create separate questions for each denomination or can I let different denominations and doctrines answer on the same question?

Comment: One might answer, "According to Calvinistic tradition, ..." or, "According to Baptist thought, ...", or "If we take into account verses such and such, this implies. . ." Are these not acceptable answers?

Comment: This question is very problematic. This is a well-known point of disagreement, and the potential for misrepresenting opposing views is too great. We do not want individual answers according to tradition because this encourages a voting contest (Catholics would eventually "win").

Answer (score 1):

Sanctification is a word that has multiple meanings within Christianity.  To answer your question we need to examine the definitions, and the teachings of the various groups.

- One definition (the more "ordinary" one) of Sanctify is "to set apart".  A person or object can be sanctified (set apart) for a particular purpose.

From http://www.theopedia.com/Sanctification

> Sanctification, or in its verbal form, sanctify, literally means "to
>   set apart" for special use or purpose, that is, to make holy or
>   sacred. Therefore, sanctification refers to the state or process of
>   being set apart, i.e. made holy. In systematic theology, the term
>   often carries a technical meaning that differs from the biblical word
>   group

In this sense, a person is sanctified by God without effort on the part of the believer.  God chooses whom He sets apart.It is solely the work of God.

The above definition often leads people to get confused, which leads them to mistake Justification to Sanctification.  Justification is, in Protestant denominations, the instant where we are saved by Grace, and are "made right" by God.  It is instant and also solely the work of God.

- The next, commonly held Protestant definition of Sanctification makes the distinction more clear.  It's a more precise theological definition.  ***If I'm reading your question correctly, I believe that this is the sense of the word you are asking about, and the answer you're looking for is found at http://carm.org/justification-and-sanctification***

> Sanctification is the process of being set apart for God's work and
>   being conformed to the image of Christ.  This conforming to Christ
>   involves the work of the person.  But it is still God working in the
>   believer to produce more of a godly character and life in the person
>   who has already been justified (Phil. 2:13).  Sanctification is not
>   instantaneous because it is not the work of God alone. The justified
>   person is actively involved in submitting to God's will, resisting
>   sin, seeking holiness, and working to be more godly (Gal. 5:22-23).
>   Significantly, sanctification has no bearing on justification.  That
>   is, even if we don't live a perfect life, we are still justified.

- Finally, there is the Catholic teaching on Sanctification, which is a bit long to summarize in this answer, but you can review an article from the Catholic Encyclopedia article here: http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06701a.htm

Comment: You should make it clear that the bottom quote comes from the CARM source above it, and not the Catholic source below it.

Answer (score 0):

Sanctification is an on-going process in the believer's life. From the perspective of God, it has already happened - it is so certain, there can be no doubt.

From our perspective, it is ongoing: we are to continue to

> "work out your salvation with fear and trembling; for it is God who is at work in you, both to will and to work for His good pleasure." ([Phil 2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%202:12-13&version=NASB)).